# using monolog with php

Tags: php, logging, monolog

I am having this code to execute in a local host and I am using wamp server for php5.3 x64 bit and I am unable to execute this code and I am very new to php.

Is there any code changes or any additions to this code?
My file name is `monolog_usage_1.php`
and I copied monolog file in src
of https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog downloaded one to the same directory.

```
use \Monolog\Logger;
use \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
include '\Monolog\Logger.php';  

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('D:\addlog.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
```

What I pass as the name To the logger('name'), is it any method name like ERROR, ALERT...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: move the include call above the use statements. Apart from that, the code you show is pretty much the same as the example on Github. Please clarify what isn't working.

Comment: @sampat what is the error you are having on your remote server ?

Comment: i am getting this error when i run this on my computer
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\monolog\monolog usage.php on line 6
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0059 671352 {main}( ) ..\monolog usage.php:0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is explicit  `Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\monolog\monolog usage.php` When using Monolog you need to include all need class with full path

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Logger.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Handler/HandlerInterface.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Handler/AbstractHandler.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php';

include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Formatter/FormatterInterface.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php';
include_once __DIR__ . '/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php';


use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/test/data.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

Comment: why not just link to the autoload.php ?